# How to find last level category of json?

Tags: javascript

I need to find the last level of the category and write it.

Example how I json can got:

```
{ category : 'One' , title : 'One category' , value : 1 },
{ subcategory : 'Two' , title : 'Two category' , value : 2 },
{ sub-subcategory : 'Three' , title : 'Three category' , value : 3 },
```

Any time i got this example:

```
{ category : 'One' , title : 'One category' , value : 1 },
{ subcategory : 'Two' , title : 'Two category' , value : 2 }
```

Any time i got json with only one category:

```
{ category : 'One' , title : 'One category' , value : 1 },
```

What I need ? I need to find last level category if choice just category i need to find just category value. If choice category and subcategory I need to find subcategory value.... If got json with category , subcategory and sub-subcategory i need to filter and get values from last -> sub-subcategory value.

I am try with:

```
 categories.map(categoryLevel => categoryLevel?.value);
```

but this is no work property.

this is also weird because i can't put it all in 1 json. than they come to me with special ions ... Example

```
{ category : 'One' , title : 'One category' , value : 1 },
{ subcategory : 'Two' , title : 'Two category' , value : 2 },
{ sub-subcategory : 'Three' , title : 'Three category' , value : 3 },
```

This is three different json... No one...

Comment: What do you mean by `this is also weird because i can't put it all in 1 json. than they come to me with special ions ...`

Comment: they come to me as separated data. they are not grouped in one array.

Comment: *"Example how I json can got"* That's not JSON. JSON requires `"` around property names, and `"` (not `'`) around strings. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: If you have different JSON data, group it in an array. If the array has sub-subcategory attribute that is your last category if not search for subcategory and category.

Comment: If `value` is the _"level"_ then look for the largest value. If `value` is not the _"level"_ but you are building this array yourself, consider structuring your data so it is consistent (i.e. add a `level: number` instead of `"sub-"` prefixes to the keys). If the "sub" prefixes are beyond your control, you'll have to search through the keys of each item in your array

Answer (score 0):

If you know there's only those 3 posibilities, you can count.`

```
if (categories.length === 3) {
  // you know there's sub-subcategory, find that
} else if (categories.length === 2) {
  // you know there's subcategory, find that    
}  else  {
  // find the category
}
```

Otherwise you can just try to find the highest level and if that's not found move lower.

```
let highest = null;
highest = categories.find(c => c['sub-subcategory']);

if (!highest) {
  // try to find subcategory
}

if (!highest) {
  try to find category
}
```

KISS

Answer (score 0):

If you can add them to an array and the last level is the longest key, then

```js
const cats = [{ "category" : 'One' , title : 'One category' , value : 1 },
{ "subcategory" : 'Two' , title : 'Two category' , value : 2 },
{ "sub-subcategory" : 'Three' , title : 'Three category' , value : 3 }]

const levels = cats
  .reduce((acc,cur) => { 
    acc.push(Object.keys(cur)
      .find(key => key.toLowerCase().endsWith('category'))); 
    return acc},[])
  .sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length)
console.log(levels.pop())
```

Comment: Assuming key of interest is always index `0` seems fragile..

Comment: @PaulS. Correct. I have updated. I do not assume the key ends with category, but that is better than before